# Monitor is showing no signal when connected to the PC. Its works perfectly fine when I connected it with a laptop

Tags: display, motherboard, hdmi, signal

My monitor is Acer Nitro VG271U 1440p 144Hz monitor. It is showing no signal when connected to the PC. Its works perfectly fine when I connected it with a laptop.

The PC is relatively just a few months old. It is a custom built. On switching the CPU on, the fans are all working, RGB lights up even the HDMI is detected, but the display shows no signal. I am assuming it has something to do with the motherboard or the HDMI port on the motherboard because when I ordered the monitor online, it did work when I connected it first for testing purpose.

Also when I tried to connect it today, there were some sparks on the IO shield, but it wasn't ESD as the flooring its tiled and I hadn't touched anything that would have created a static discharge. I was also holding the insulated part of the HDMI.

PC configuration:

- **CPU**: i7 10700k
- **RAM**: Gskill 16GB 3600MHz
- **Motherboard**: Gigabyte z490 UD.
- **PSU**: Antec modular 750W 80+ gold PSU
- **GPU**: No GPU as of yet.

Comment: So the monitor works fine. This means the problem is in the computer. If you have a discrete GPU you could swap that and see. If you are using onboard video you'll need to either install a discrete GPU, or swap out your mainboard.

Answer (score 0):

So the monitor works fine. This means the problem is in the computer. If you have a discrete GPU you could swap that and see. If you are using onboard video you'll need to either install a discrete GPU, or swap out your mainboard.

Or, take it to a qualified local PC technician who can do this for you.

Comment: I reseated the RAM module to another RAM slot and it works fine now.